# Pass parent class reference as argument in derived class in C++

Tags: c++, oop, multiple-inheritance

I'm new to C++ and am trying to achieve the following design.

```
class A { do (); doMore (); } // abstract
class B { do (); doMore (); } // abstract

class X : public A, public B // Also abstract
{        
    foo() {
        // common code
        A::do();
        A::doMore();
    }
    bar() {
        // common code
        B::do();
        B::doMore();
    }
}
```

Both A and B provide implementations of `do()` and `doMore()`.
How can I extract the common code that the new function takes an arg that calls the method in the correct parent class?

Something like

```
X::newMethod(arg_that_indicates_parent_class) {
    // common code
    arg_that_indicates_parent_class::do();
    arg_that_indicates_parent_class::doMore();
}
```

Then call it like so

```
newMethod(pass_A_somehow);
newMethod(pass_B_somehow);
```

Looks like runtime polymorphism, but not quite (or is it?)... as it is within a child class...

Is this design itself just trash and there is a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the idea is that `do` and `doMore` will be present in both `A` and `B` and those are the functions specifically you wish to call, you could
use a template function like so:

```
class X : public A, public B // Also abstract
{        
    template <typename T>
    void newMethod()
    {
        T::do();
        T::doMore();
    }
}
```

Then using it explicitly, you could then do it like so:

```
X x;
x.newMethod<A>();
x.newMethod<B>();
```

This has the added benefit of catching some errors at compile time, that is, if you try and pass a `C` and it **does not** have
the `do` and `doMore` functions defined, you will receive a complier error (instead of a run-time crash).

This also lets you utilize the `std::enable_if` functionality if you are using C++1x.

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 1):

Just factor out the "common code", and make it, well, common:

```
class X : public A, public B // Also abstract
{        
    void foo() {
        commoncode();
        A::do();
        A::doMore();
    }
    void bar() {
        commoncode();
        B::do();
        B::doMore();
    }

    void commoncode()
    {
         // Your common code
    }
}
```

That's the most simple, straightforward way. Another alternative way would be closer in line to your "pass me a pointer of some kind" intended approach:

```
class X : public A, public B // Also abstract
{        
    void call_a()
        A::do();
        A::doMore();
    }
    void call_b()
        B::do();
        B::doMore();
    }

    void commoncode( void (X::*ptr)() )
    {
         // Your common code

         (this->*ptr)();
    }
}
```

And the parameter to `commoncode()` would be either

```
&X::call_a
```

or

```
&X::call_b
```

Comment: `common code()` was probably not the best way to put it. I just put it like for the sake of brevity. The common code is actually all around the calls to `do()` and `doMore()`. Your second suggestion looks promising. I'll give it a shot !